# Disable a radio button after confirm

Tags: javascript, php

I tried to research and tried many options but still not working. After the user click the radio button and confirm it i need to disable the radio buttons

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getVote(int) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    if (confirm("Your vote is for " + int)) {

      xmlhttp.open("GET", "save.php?vote=" + int, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
      window.location.reload();

    } else {
      alert("Choose another candidate ");
    }

  }

  function getPosition(String) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "vote.php?position=" + String, true);

    xmlhttp.send();

  }
</script>
```

and this is the radio button that the user will click

```
     echo "<td><input type='radio' name='vote' value='$row[candidate_name]' onclick='getVote(this.value)' /></td>";
```

this is save.php when the user click the radio button

```
   <?php
       require('connection.php');
       $vote = $_REQUEST['vote'];

   $checkposition=mysql_query("SELECT candidate_position FROM voting_tbCandidates WHERE candidate_name='$vote'");
     while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($checkposition)){
  session_start();

  if($row['candidate_position']=="PRESIDENT"){
  $_SESSION['vote_president']=$row['candidate_position'];
  }elseif($row['candidate_position']=="VICE"){
   $_SESSION['vote_vice']=$row['candidate_position'];
   }elseif($row['candidate_position']=="MUSE"){
    $_SESSION['vote_muse']=$row['candidate_position'];
    }elseif($row['candidate_position']=="SECRETARY"){
    $_SESSION['vote_secretary']=$row['candidate_position'];
    }elseif($row['candidate_position']=="ESCORT"){
     $_SESSION['vote_escort']=$row['candidate_position'];
   }elseif($row['candidate_position']=="AUDITOR"){
    $_SESSION['vote_auditor']=$row['candidate_position'];
      }
      }
     mysql_query("UPDATE voting_tbCandidates SET candidate_cvotes=candidate_cvotes+1 WHERE candidate_name='$vote'");

 mysql_close($con);
  ?>
```

Comment: will you show your `save.php` and full html file?

Comment: After get vote you are reloading a page so you have to check there that have you given a vote to "$row[candidate_name]" than make it disable otherwise enable.

Comment: I update my question sir @B. Desai

Answer (score 0):

You are sending just the value back to the function. It would be easier to send the whole element to the function and pick out the parts that you need. For example: 
Change

```
onclick='getVote(this.value)'
```

to

```
onclick='getVote(this)'
```

Change

```
function getVote(int)
```

to

```
function getVote(obj) {
  var int = obj.value;
```

Before the `xmlhttp.open("GET", "save.php?vote=" + int, true);` add the line

```
obj.setAttribute('disabled','disabled'); // I think this would work
```

Comment: i tried this but still not working but thank you for answering sir! maybe its working or maybe because it is submitting form and i think it's refreshing when the form submit so the disable will be gone?

Comment: @KosakiOnodera, I missed the code where you were reloading the page once the AJAX call had been called. Did you know this defeats the purpose of AJAX? If you want a page reload then simply submit the form to save.php.

Comment: Hmm i don't know sir. Can you also help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

set disable property to true on confirm and false for else.

modified function should be look like this

```
function getVote(obj) {
var int = obj.value;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

} else { // code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

if (confirm("Your vote is for " + int)) {
  obj.disabled = true;
  //xmlhttp.open("GET","save.php?vote="+int,true);
  //xmlhttp.send();
  //  window.location.reload();

} else {
  obj.disabled = false;
  alert("Choose another candidate ");
}
```

}

and pass the object of input element during function call

```
<td>
  <input type='radio' name='vote' value='45' onclick='getVote(this)'/>
</td>
```

here is working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net6mcd5bq7/